# How can I play downloaded mp3 files with Xamarin.Forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, download-manager

I want to play mp3 files with the program that I will perform. I can play the file without downloading the files, but I can not play the file which I downloaded. Can you help me with this?

I am working on the `Xamarin.Forms` project. I download the mp3 file from the internet via API. But I can not figure out where the downloaded file is specifically registered. I share the codes that I wrote on the IOS layer and on the PCL side with you.

Note: I can check that the download is successful and check the download status.

Note2: I use `Xam.Plugins.DownloadManager` for the download.

The code that I wrote at the IOS layer.

```
public void SetDownloadPath()    
{
    CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new System.Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file =>
    {
        string fileName = (new NSUrl(file.Url, false)).LastPathComponent;
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);

    });
}
```

The code I wrote in ViewModel.

```
    public async Task<DownloadItem> AddBookDownload(BookInfo _bookInfo)
    {
        var downloadItem = new DownloadItem
        {
            BookName = _bookInfo.Title,
            DownloadID = _bookInfo.ID,
            DistinctionCount = _bookInfo.SectionCount 
        };
        var sections = await LibraryClient.GetBookSections(_bookInfo.ID);
        downloadItem.Sections = sections.Data;
        if (downloadItem.Sections == null || downloadItem.Sections.Count <0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var linkFile =
            CrossDownloadManager.Current.CreateDownloadFile(downloadItem.Sections.FirstOrDefault()
                ?.GetLink()
                .ToString());
        downloadItem.DownloadedTaskList.Add(linkFile.GetHashCode(), downloadItem);


        linkFile.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Update UI text-fields
            var downloadFile = (IDownloadFile) sender;
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case nameof(IDownloadFile.Status):
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        downloadItem.DownloadState = downloadFile.Status;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Download Status: " + downloadFile.Status);
                    });
                    break;
                case nameof(IDownloadFile.StatusDetails):
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Download Details: " + downloadFile.StatusDetails);
                    });
                    break;
                case nameof(IDownloadFile.TotalBytesExpected):
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("BytesExpected" + downloadFile.TotalBytesExpected);
                    });
                    break;
                case nameof(IDownloadFile.TotalBytesWritten):
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("BytesWritten" + downloadFile.TotalBytesWritten);
                    });
                    break;
            }

            // Update UI if download-status changed.
            if (e.PropertyName == "Status")
                switch (((IDownloadFile) sender).Status)
                {
                    case DownloadFileStatus.COMPLETED:
                        downloadItem.DownloadState = DownloadFileStatus.COMPLETED;
                        DistinctionCount = downloadItem.DistinctionCount;
                        BookName = downloadItem.BookName;
                        DownloadedBooks.Add(downloadItem);
                        NativeServices.DownloadService.SaveDownloadsItem(downloadItem);
                        NativeServices.MediaPlayerService.PlayFromFile(Path.GetFileName(CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile.ToString()));
                        Debug.WriteLine("Download Completed");
                        break;
                    case DownloadFileStatus.FAILED:
                        downloadItem.DownloadState = DownloadFileStatus.FAILED;
                        Debug.WriteLine("Download Failed");
                        break;
                    case DownloadFileStatus.CANCELED:
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Debug.WriteLine("Download Cancelled"); });
                        break;
                }

            // Update UI while donwloading.
            if (e.PropertyName == "TotalBytesWritten" || e.PropertyName == "TotalBytesExpected")
            {
                var bytesExpected = ((IDownloadFile) sender).TotalBytesExpected;
                var bytesWritten = ((IDownloadFile) sender).TotalBytesWritten;

                if (bytesExpected > 0)
                {
                    var percentage = Math.Round(bytesWritten / bytesExpected * 100);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Debug.WriteLine("Downloading" + percentage + "%"); });
                }
            }
        };

        CrossDownloadManager.Current.Start(linkFile);
        return downloadItem;
    }
```

Comment: You need to use `Dependency Service` on different platforms to play mp3, [Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22085/playing-audio-files-in-xamarin-forms) may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Audio file Xamrin form sample on below URL :

[Audio File Integration Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleAudioForms)